# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest takes minuttes to send after IOS7 /Xcode5

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

I'm trying to update my app to be compatible with IOS7 using Xcode 5
Before this it was built in X-code 4.5 (or something like this)

I know have trouble with sending a post request to a server, that just simply needs to update some data in a database.

Worked perfectly before, but now its just weird. It can take 2 minuttes before i can see a change on the server, so its like the URL command is being queed (against my will!)

The code that worked flawless before (update was instant):

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *p_request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [p_request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sql_url]];
        [p_request setCachePolicy:0] ;
        [p_request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [p_request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [p_request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [p_request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSData *content = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:p_request returningResponse:&response error:&error] ;
```

I have tried several standard variables for CachePolicy. I just want it to execute the URL call immediately

Comment: Using a cache policy of `0` (i.e. `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`) is unlikely to cause the problem, but something like `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` seems more prudent. Other than that, it's hard to diagnose this on the basis of the information provided. I might run this through [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) and confirm request and response. Or put something unique in the server response that the Objective-C code can examine and confirm whether cached response was received or not.

Comment: Yes its strange.. I used NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData but to no avail..
Then instead i used the old web AJAX trick with adding a random number to the URL, and now it works..
I have had nothing but problems since IOS7 came out :(